# SQL table filter on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which is having a ID values of other tables. What I need to do is based on a set of column, filter should be assigned and including that if any unique row found then it should also get added to result.

My SQL table is as below:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   2
1   2   1   1   1
1   2   1   1   0
2   1   1   1   3
2   1   1   1   4
2   1   2   2   1
3   1   1   2   0
3   1   1   2   1
```

Here, **Columns** are: **A, B, C, D, E**.

**Filters** needs to be assigned are as below:

> 1. Value of column A,B,C,D will be same.
> 2. If value of column A will be same but values of **B,C,D** will be different it **should be added in the result**.
> 3. For each row in the result value of column **E** will be **minimum**

As per above filters, query's out put should be as below:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   1   1   1   0
1   2   1   1   0
2   1   1   1   3
2   1   2   2   1
3   1   1   2   0
```

What I have come up till now is:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TestTable t1, 
     TestTable t2
WHERE   (t1.A = t2.A
    AND t1.B = t2.B
    AND t1.C = t2.C
    AND t1.D = t2.D
    AND t1.E < t2.E)
```

But in this query, I'm not getting the unique row which is having same value for column **A** but different values for columns **B,C,D**.

Comment: Your second condition doesn't make sense.  Your third is ambiguous . . . the value of `E` is minimum over what?

Comment: In your expected output please specify which row satisfies which condition that will help us to understand better.

Comment: also helpful if you would include the DDL's and inserts as well:-)/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want:

```
select A, B, C, D, MIN(E)
from testtable t
group by A, B, C, D;
```

At the very least, this produces the output that you have specified.

Comment: Don't want to complain but the question (even if it's messy) was in regard to two tables and some logic between them

Comment: @BartoszX I read it as "the table contains rows whose values are foreign keys from other tables", would be interested to know what's right.